# Create a dynamic table in Tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api

What I am trying to do is simply replicate an excel sheet on Tableau. However, my worksheet shall contain many columns having been calculated using other columns. Calculating a field is not much in Tableau I understand but I want to see the changes happening in the calculated field as one enters the data in the parent field on the dashboard directly. For example I put up the following data on Tableau:

x   y(=x*5) z(=x+10)
1   5       11
2   10      12
3   15      13
4   20      14
5   25      15

I would like to see the values of y and z change automatically as the values of x are fed in directly on the dashboard.

I am not able to figure out how to accomplish this on tableau. Would be highly obliged on any help extended. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but if you still need this to answer then here is my speculations. I am assuming this is how you want your table to be:

```
| Column X | Column Y| Column Z  | A  | B  | C  | ... |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   2      | 10(2*5) | 12(2+10)  | 2  | 4  | 1  | ... |
|   4      | 20(4*5) | 14(4+10)  | 3  | 1  | 3  | ... |
|   8      | 40(8*5) | 18(8+10)  | 6  | 0  | 9  | ... |
|   .      | .       | .         | .  | .  | .  | ... |
|   .      | .       | .         | .  | .  | .  | ... |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

You can create calculated fields for `ColumnY` and `ColumnZ` . In calculated columns you can you use `lookup` to find value in a particular column (here `ColumnX`) and perform calculations on it.

Here is how you create your calculated column:

```
ColumnY 

LOOKUP(SUM(ColumnX),0) * 5
```

and

```
ColumnZ

LOOKUP(SUM(ColumnX),0) + 10
```

Have a look at this LOOKUP function [Lookup Table calculation function](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.htm#lookupexpression-offset)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially talking about parameters.  A complete detailed article can be found [here](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-parameters)

> Parameters are dynamic values that can replace constant values in
>   calculations and can serve as filters. For example, you might have a
>   calculated field that returns True if Sales are greater than $500,000,
>   and otherwise returns False. Using a parameter, you can replace the
>   constant value of $500,000 in the calculated field with a parameter
>   than you can change dynamically using the Parameter control.

In your case, you can simply create a parameter X, that will be entered by user on the fly, and then in turn use x in the calculations of y and z, thus accomplishing your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is I wanted the execution just similar to excel files, i.e., the variable x is a column and not a discrete value, drop-down list or range. I might change 3 values in x at a time and so forth. I tried achieving the same through parameter but does not happen like that. Won't give me a tabular view.. :(

Comment: Don't compare Excel and Tableau on the same par. Tableau is not meant for data input, you can parameterize your visualizations, but in your case if you actually want to modify the entire column [ x being a column in your case], i guess that lies out of the scope of tableau

Comment: Okay, it's just that I wanted to incorporate all of the things together on the dashboard. But anyway, thank you for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If input is of concern to you than Tableau also enables you to create user based input into your parameters. You can create columns that run off these input, such as Column 1 = X (Parameter 1) * Y (Parameter 2)

To set this up create the parameters, name them, and define their input ranges. For example say Parameter 1 can take integers from 1-1000. Then do the same for Parameter 2.

Next create a calculated field where field = X*Y

Do this for as many variables (parameters) and as many equations (columns) as you want! there you go, the dynamic table.